# Avoiding Loops in SQL, #temptables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have heard/read people say that "loops are bad mkay" or "If you think you need a loop, you don't". I understand the processing and speed implications of running a loop on a database but are there exceptions to this rule? I am trying to resolve an issue where I need to, infrequently, insert 80 lines into a table all with the exact same information except for an ID field.

I have written two queries which in theory will do what I need but I would like to know if the query containing the loop should be avoided at all costs, if the #temptable method is sound, and if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do outside of the two options I've presented.  Thanks in advance.

For some background I have tableB which contains an ID field, the field being a FK to an ID field on TableA.

Query 1

```
DECLARE @minid as int = 1
DECLARE @maxid as int = 100
WHILE @minid <= @maxid
    BEGIN
    SET @minid = @maxid + 1
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE eID = @minid AND Name = 'B')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO TableA (eID, B, C)
            VALUES
            (@minid, B, C)
        END
    IF @minid = @maxid BREAK
    END
```

Query 2

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
eID
B
C 

INSERT INTO #TempTable (eID)
SELECT eID
FROM TableB
WHERE (code to specify which eIDs to pull out of table b)

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET B = 'XX', C = 'XX'

INSERT INTO TableA (eID, B, C)
SELECT eID, B, C
FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: Instead of asking us which one runs better, you should run them both and compare their execution-plans.

Comment: Also, if you want to insert 80 records, use `INSERT INTO tableName ( x, y, z ) SELECT x, y, z FROM GENERATE_SERIES( 1, 80, 1 );`. _Much simpler_, you'll agree.

Comment: Sorry still very new to SQL.  This is Interesting though, I didn't realize this was an option, to google I go, thanks!

Comment: The "correct" way to do what you are trying to do is build the data you need in a single query, and then convert it to an update. You don't need a loop, and you shouldn't need a temp table. You might use a CTE. And the reason not to use loops is not just for performance, its using SQL the way it is meant to be used. Its cleaner and clearer, and easier to maintain when done correctly.

Comment: And if you want help writing such a query you need to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. As it stands your question is likely to get closed as "opinion-based" because no one can say categorically one is better than another, thats down to your preferences and use-cases.

Comment: And to complete your edification, [Codd's paper is required reading](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf).

Comment: [go 80](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16) do the trick.

Comment: For what it's worth, in your first query the while loop would theoretically only execute once, as you're setting `@minid` to `maxid + 1`, which will mean on the second evaluation `@minid` will be greater than `@maxid`

Comment: For a one time action involving 80, 100, 1000, or even 10k rows, just do what is simplest. Time spent optimizing usually exceeds the savings. When looping becomes an issue is when you are repeatedly processing 10,000s, 100,000s, or 1,000,000s or rows or perhaps looping through 1000s of accounts of 1000s of transactions each. That when you should look into what it would take to recode that into a single set-based operation. The SQL query optimizer has a much better chance (though not guaranteed) of morphing your query into an efficient plan many times faster than the looping solution.

Answer (score 0):

They are *both* wrong. You don't need temp tables or loops. Just use `GENERATE_SERIES` to generate a bunch of rows.

```sql
INSERT INTO TableA
  (eID, B, C)
SELECT
  g.value,
  'XX',
  'XX'
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000) AS g;
```

In older versions of SQL Server you can use one of Itzik Ben-Gan's [numbers functions](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).